# How to detect the side of collision?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to remake breakout, and my ball occasionally jumps through tiles altogether, or bounces off incorrectly. I think I figured out the problem is that my code to detect whether the ball is coming from the top, bottom, or side, doesn't account for the fact that the "step" size of the ball can make it land inside of a tile. The only thing I've tried that has prevented these bugs from happening has been to decrease the step size, but that makes the ball move slower than I want it to. So, how can I keep the speed of the ball the same while still accurately detecting which side it collided with?

```
Vector2 ballCenter = new Vector2();
                Vector2 tileCenter = new Vector2();
                ballCenter = ball.getHitbox().getCenter(ballCenter);
                tileCenter = tiles.get(i-1).getHitbox().getCenter(tileCenter);



                if(ballCenter.y-ball.sprite.getHeight()/2>tileCenter.y){
                    ball.velocity.y = Math.max((-1*ball.velocity.y)+2,10);
                }
                else if(ballCenter.y+ball.sprite.getHeight()/2<tileCenter.y){
                    ball.velocity.y = Math.max((-1*ball.velocity.y)-1,-10);
                }
                else
                    ball.velocity.x *=-1;
```

Comment: If you keep the current location and the previous location then you can say things like "if the current location is above the brick and the previous location was below then the ball was moving upwards" and so on.  And then you could potentially calculate where the ball first touched the brick and at what angle in order to calculate the resulting path.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your code detects whether the ball is currently colliding with the tile at the time when the step occurs.  The problem is that unless you have incredibly tiny step sizes then the likelihood of the collision occurring precisely at the right time to coincide with a step is minimal.  Since you have collisions occurring between steps you have things like ball jumping through tiles and completely ignoring them.

One solution to this is to change the manner in which you do collision detection. Instead of checking to see whether the ball has hit the tile at this point in time, you need to check whether the ball has hit the tile at any point in time between the current step and the one prior.

Since you have both the location and velocity of the ball, and I am assuming static tiles, you can model this as finding the intersection of the line from the old location of the ball to the new location of the ball (old location + velocity assuming no collision).

Then, if there is an intersection (collision) you can employ a more involved processing.

So, the pseudo code would look something like this:

```
// use some basic geometry to find intersections between the ball's motion vector 
// and the tiles bounding square
if (isCollision(ball, tile)) 
{
   // If there is a collision then find out how far through the step it occurred
   // i.e.: 0 = start, 1 = end, 0.5 = half way through
   collision_time = findCollisionTime(ball, tile); 

   //process the part of the step before the collision
   ball.x = ball.x + (ball.velocity.x * collision_time);
   ball.y = ball.y + (ball.velocity.y * collision_time);
   //or however you want to do it.

   //update the velocity to for the collision
   ball.velocity.x = ...
   ball.velocity.y = ...

   //process the part of the step after the collision
   ball.x = ball.x + (ball.velocity.x * (1-collision_time));
   ball.y = ball.y + (ball.velocity.y * (1-collision_time));
}
```

Note: the approach I have shown above assumes that only the ball moves, and that it will never collide with more than one tile in a step. It should be easy enough to allow for multiple collisions with some adaptation and a while loop. Allowing for non-static collisions requires a bit more thinking.

Alternatively, you could look into a physics engine to do all this for you.

Comment: In regards to the physics engine, I was wondering if that might be the solution. Still, it's always good to know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user3316768 Well, it is not necessarily how it *is* done, but it's what I came up with off the top of my head. Incidentally here's a [link to the libgdx physics engine wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Physics).